# How do I put the Pulll to refresh indicator above the header in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

On iOS apps when the header is `big` pull to refresh brings down even the header and shows the refresh icon above the header.  The [Refresh Control](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol#refreshlayoutconstssize) puts it relative to the FlatList so if I pull to refresh the header goes down and the icon gets half rendered on a **NativeStack** the non-native stack will not do the big text effect.

I am trying to replicate the behaviour only on iOS and on Android it would still be under the header.

The way I had it before was to make the header as part of the flat list only on iOS but that seemed a bit overkill.  Is there cleaner way of doing this?

https://snack.expo.dev/@trajano/multi-tab-navigation-with-refresh shows the issue

I am trying to replicate the same behaviour as shown in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in RN 0.63 and it is fixed on RN 0.64 which Expo is not using as of SDK 42

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/395#issuecomment-884556932

Just have to wait to get it done or pay extra.